# Ejecutar función Javascript dentro de otra función en evento onclick

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código, que reproduce un sonido cuando presionas la imagen

```js
function iniciar() {

  console.log("Iniciando Audio");
  var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
  audio.play();

  console.log("Zoom Out a la imagen");
  var sorpresa = document.getElementById("sorpresa");
  sorpresa.style.animation = 'zoomOut 2s';

  console.log("Oscureciendo fondo");
  var layer = document.getElementById("bg-layer");
  layer.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)";

  console.log("Ocultar imagen despues del zoomOut");
  setTimeout(() => {
    sorpresa.style.display = "none";
  }, 2000);

}
```

```css
#bg-layer {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#sorpresa {
  z-index: 999;
  filter: drop-shadow(6px 6px 12px black);
  animation: headShake 2s ease-in-out infinite;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@-webkit-keyframes headShake {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  6.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-9deg);
    transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-9deg);
  }
  18.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(7deg);
    transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(7deg);
  }
  31.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-5deg);
    transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-5deg);
  }
  43.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(3deg);
    transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(3deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes headShake {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  6.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-9deg);
    transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-9deg);
  }
  18.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(7deg);
    transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(7deg);
  }
  31.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-5deg);
    transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-5deg);
  }
  43.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(3deg);
    transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(3deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}


/* Zooming exits */

@-webkit-keyframes zoomOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
    transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes zoomOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
    transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">


<audio id="audio" style="display: none" controls>
    <source type="audio/mpeg" src="https://samplelib.com/lib/preview/mp3/sample-9s.mp3">
</audio>


<div id="bg-layer" class="w-100 min-vh-100 position-absolute d-flex align-items-center">
  <div class="position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle" onclick="iniciar()">
    <img id="sorpresa" class="img-fluid" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fW44.png" alt="Sorpresa">
  </div>
</div>
```

Básicamente, al hacer `onclick` se ejecutan algunas funciones sencillas de CSS. Todo correcto y funcional.

Al finalizar el audio, detectado con el [evento `ended`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event), se revierten algunas funciones (ocultando elementos en pantalla).

```js
function iniciar() {

  console.log("Iniciando Sorpresa");
  var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
  audio.play();


  var sorpresa = document.getElementById("sorpresa");
  sorpresa.style.animation = 'zoomOut 2s';

  var layer = document.getElementById("bg-layer");
  layer.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)";

  setTimeout(() => {
    sorpresa.style.display = "none";
  }, 2000);


  // Ejecutar al finalizar el audio
  const audioFin = document.querySelector('audio');

  audioFin.addEventListener('ended', (event) => {
    console.log('Audio finalizado');

   
      const quitar1 = document.getElementById("bg-layer");      
      const quitar4 = document.getElementById("audio");

      quitar1.style.setProperty("display", "none", "important");
      quitar4.style.display = "none";
    



  });

}
```

```css
#bg-layer {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#sorpresa {
  z-index: 999;
  filter: drop-shadow(6px 6px 12px black);
  animation: headShake 2s ease-in-out infinite;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@-webkit-keyframes headShake {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  6.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-9deg);
    transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-9deg);
  }
  18.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(7deg);
    transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(7deg);
  }
  31.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-5deg);
    transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-5deg);
  }
  43.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(3deg);
    transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(3deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes headShake {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  6.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-9deg);
    transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-9deg);
  }
  18.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(7deg);
    transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(7deg);
  }
  31.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-5deg);
    transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-5deg);
  }
  43.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(3deg);
    transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(3deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}


/* Zooming exits */

@-webkit-keyframes zoomOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
    transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes zoomOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
    transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">


<audio id="audio" style="display: none" controls>
        <source type="audio/mpeg" src="https://samplelib.com/lib/preview/mp3/sample-6s.mp3">
    </audio>


<div id="bg-layer" class="w-100 min-vh-100 position-absolute d-flex align-items-center">
  <div class="position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle" onclick="iniciar()">
    <img id="sorpresa" class="img-fluid" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fW44.png" alt="Sorpresa">
  </div>
</div>
```

Nuevamente, esto funciona correctamente.

**Lo que necesito** es poder cerrar estos elementos en pantalla, por si el usuario simplemente no quiere darle clic a la imagen y que se ejecute la función `iniciar()`.

Para ello, creé una simple etiqueta `span` que me permita cerrar los elementos en pantalla con el evento `onclick`, que a su vez debería ejecutar la función `quitarFuncion()`

```
<span id="cerrar" onclick="quitarFuncion()">X</span>

// Ejecutar al finalizar el audio
        const audioFin = document.querySelector('audio');

        audioFin.addEventListener('ended', (event) => {
            console.log('Audio finalizado');

            function quitarFuncion() {
                const quitar1 = document.getElementById("bg-layer");               
                const quitar4 = document.getElementById("audio");


                quitar1.style.setProperty("background-color", "transparent", "important");
                quitar4.style.display = "none";
            }
```

Pero esto no funciona, alguna idea?

Comment: Por qué no defines `quitarFuncion()` afuera de la función `iniciar()`?

Comment: donde esta "hb-bg-layer" ?. Por otro lado lo que dice @Fedex7501 es bueno, saca la quitarFuncion() fuera de todo y llamala desde el listener ended, solo no olvides recibir el event

Comment: por otro lado, debes darle al span position: absolute y z-index: 1 para que al presionarlo haga efecto ya que esta tapado por los otros elementos

Comment: @HernánGarcia fue un error al momento de copiar el código. Gracias por la corrección. Lo de estilizar el span lo conozco, pero no es la prioridad sobre lo que quiero lograr. Puede ser un enlace, un botón o un div.

Comment: @FedericoMeza debería duplicar la función `quiarFuncion()`? O dejarla fuera y llamar a que se ejecute dentro de `iniciar()`? Es que poco comprendo sobre la ejecución de JS y el DOM

Comment: Deberías declararla afuera y llamarla desde `iniciar`

Comment: Agradezco si puedes darme luces sobre cómo lo implementarías, me serviría de mucho tu ayuda

Comment: quitarFuncion() sacala y ponla fuera de todo y el listener te quedaria: audioFin.addEventListener('ended', quitarFuncion) de esta forma la funcion queda global y la puedes llamar desde distintos lugares